# Как поймать клик на конкретном элементе списка? Чистый js

Tags: javascript, циклы, события

Есть список из нескольких элементов. Хочу навесить класс на элемент по которому кликнул. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('div')].forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
```